# Cookies used in Google login

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, google-api, google-oauth

The first time I go to log in to Gmail (or another Google service), Google asks me to enter my Gmail address and password. The next time I go to log in, Google already knows my account and only asks for a password. Is there a cookie I can delete before going to the login page, so that Google ALWAYS asks me which account I want to log in to.

This is for a web-app. I can run any JavaScript code, including deleting cookies and then redirect the browser to Google's login page.

Answer (score 2):

The cookies you refer to are those specific to security, as detailed on the "Types of cookies used by Google" documentation [page](https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/types/).

As an alternative to finding and deleting certain cookies, you might simply disable the saving of passwords in Gmail itself, as indicated in the "Stop saving my username or password" paragraph of the "Gmail remembers my login email and password" [page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12095?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).